# Long title in pdf export resizes the plot

Tags: plotting, graphics

When using GraphicsGrid to make multiple plots, if one plot has a longer title, the sizing gets messed up when the image is exported to pdf.  Below is a massively simplified example code,

```
gj0 = Plot[BesselJ[0, x], {x, 0, 10}, Frame -> True, 
FrameLabel -> {{Style["Label", Black, 17], 
  None}, {Style[" ", Black, 19], 
  Style["Longer than long Population Fraction 100 x 500", Black, 
   22]}}];
gy1 = Plot[BesselY[0, x], {x, 1, 10}, Frame -> True, 
FrameLabel -> {{Style[" ", Black, 17], 
  None}, {Style[" ", Black, 19], 
  Style["Population Fraction 100 x 500", Black, 22]}}];
gj2 = Plot[BesselJ[0, x], {x, 0, 10}, Frame -> True, 
FrameLabel -> {{Style["Label", Black, 17], 
  None}, {Style[
   "\[LeftAngleBracket]\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Theta]\), 
StyleBox[\"int\",\nFontSlant->\"Italic\"]]\)\[RightAngleBracket]", 
   Black, 19], 
  Style["Population Fraction 100 x 500", Black, 22]}}];
gy3 = Plot[BesselY[0, x], {x, 1, 10}, Frame -> True, 
FrameLabel -> {{Style[" ", Black, 17], 
  None}, {Style[
   "\[LeftAngleBracket]\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Theta]\), 
StyleBox[\"int\",\nFontSlant->\"Italic\"]]\)\[RightAngleBracket]", 
   Black, 19], 
  Style["Population Fraction 100 x 500", Black, 22]}}];

test = GraphicsGrid[{{gj0, gy1}, {gj2, gy3}}, Spacings -> {-20, 0}]

Export["~/Documents/Latex/figures/test.pdf", test, 
ImageSize -> {1800, 1075}]
```

Which results in the following image,

[image]

Which is interesting because in Mathematica the image looks just fine.

Also, if the title is shortened up, then it appears just fine as a pdf.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but I wanted to mention to that I gave up on grid-layouts in figures a long time ago. It's possible to do it, but it is troublesome, and you can expect to run into difficulties like this from time to time. Now I use [SciDraw](http://scidraw.nd.edu/) exclusively for producing publications quality figures arranged in a grid. SciDraw is also a lot of work both to learn and to use, but it is at least reliable, and thus not frustrating. The reason why it's a lot of work to use is that it effectively forces to me to control every detail of the figure manually.

Comment: But when I a producing publication figures, I would spend a lot of time on these details *ayway*, to make the result perfect. Thus in the end SciDraw is still a time saver for such work. For producing quick and dirty results to show at a meeting, SciDraw tends to be too much trouble.